# trigger js when fullcalendar has an overlapped event

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

Is there a possibility to trigger a js function when there is overlapped event?  I tried googling it but I can't find the feature to detect overlap.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you give a little more information? What events are overlapping, and what exactly are you trying to do when it happens?

Comment: example for event_a 7:30 am to 9Am wed and it is overlapped by 8am to 9:30am wed also. I want to trigger a javascript function like pnotify alerting that there is a conflict of events.

Comment: you just have to iterate the events array and compare the start/end dates (easy using momentJS).

Comment: im not using dates , but day of week (dow)

Comment: when exactly do you want to to make this comparison? You need to be more specific about your requirements - at the moment your question is vague and unclear. Also, have you tried to research or attempt this yourself at all? Questions that don't show any initial research or coding effort tend to get closed or downvoted - just a friendly hint :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be found in `selectOverlap` and `eventOverlap` which is documented at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/ respectively.

I have a calendar that accepts products, and I needed to make sure no one could ever add duplicate products to the same day. I achieved this by doing something like this:

```
selectOverlap: function (event) {
                if (event.title === $('#productDd option:selected').text()) {
                    AlertDialog("Duplicate Product", "You may not add a duplicate product.");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
```

I then also had to detect if a product would be duplicate when someone dragged a product from one day to another, I did that using `eventOverlap`:

```
eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
                return stillEvent.title !== movingEvent.title;
            },
```

In your case, you want to fire a function or maybe an alert, you could do something like:

```
selectOverlap: function (event) {
                //fireFunction();
                //or
                alert("fire function");
            },
```

the event has quite a few other properties, in my case I only took advantage of title, but in your case you should look at the dates, or times, etc.